# How to create readable stream from a MediaStream object

Tags: node.js, electron

In electron, I can get a MediaStream object, but how to convert it to a readable stream.
The MediaStream does not have pipe method, how to read it?

```
const { desktopCapturer } = require('electron')
desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'] }).then(async sources => {
  for (const source of sources) {
    if (source.name === 'Electron') {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: false,
          video: {
            mandatory: {
              chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
              chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
            }
          }
        })
        handleStream(stream)
      } catch (e) {
        handleError(e)
      }
      return
    }
  }
})

function handleStream (stream) {
 // this is the classic usage of MediaStream
  //const video = document.querySelector('video')
  //video.srcObject = stream

 // but I want to do something like this
   var fs = require("fs");
   var writerStream = fs.createWriteStream('output.mp4');
   stream.pipe(writerStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am definitely not an expert but if the purpose is to save recorded video to the file system you could use [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).